# Time Variable Is Not Defined in Discord.JS

Tags: discord.js

My `setTimeout()` is used for a certain amount of `time` as the user states. So, if the user put in `20`, the muted member would be muted for 20 minutes. The problem I am having is that the `time` says it is `undefined` at the end. I'm not sure why it's not working. The syntax would be something like `!mute user time reason`.

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "mute",
  description: "Mute those members!",
  execute(message, args) {
    const {RichEmbed} = require("discord.js");
    setTimeout(() => {
      if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.channel.send("You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this command. Please try again");

    let muteMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.members.get(args[0]);
    if(!muteMember) return message.channel.send("You did not provide a member to mute. Please provide a user to mute");

    let time = parseInt(args[2]) * 60000;
    if(!time) return message.channel.send("You did not provide how long to mute this member. Please provide a time in minutes");

    let reason = args.slice(2).join(" ");
    if(!reason) reason = "No reason provided";

    if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.channel.send("I do not have sufficient permissions to mute this member. Please try again");





  let muteRole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Muted");

  if(!muteRole) {
    try {
      muteRole = message.guild.createRole({
        name: "Muted",
        permissions: []
      }) 
      message.guild.channels.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
        await channel.overwritePermissions(muteRole, {
          SEND_MESSAGE: false,
          ADD_REACTIONS: false,
          SEND_TTS_MESSAGES: false,
          ATTACH_FILES: false,
          SPEAK: false
        })
      })
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.stack);
    }
  }

    muteMember.addRole(muteRole.id). then(() => {
      message.delete();
      muteMember.send(`You have been muted in ${message.guild.name} for ${reason}`).catch(err =>console.log(err));
      message.channel.send(`${muteMember.user.username} has been successfully muted`);

      let muteEmbed = new RichEmbed()
      .setColor("#FF0000")
      .addField("Moderation Action", "mute")
      .addField("Muted Member", muteMember.user.username)
      .addField("Moderator", message.author.username)
      .addField("Reason", reason)
      .addField("Date:", message.createdAt.toLocaleAString());

    let modChannel = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "mod-log");

    modChannel.send(muteEmbed);

    })
    }, time)

  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the `time` argument first before the `reason` argument since at the moment you're putting the `time` variable into the `reason` variable

```js
if (isNaN(args[1]) return message.reply('Please enter a valid number');
let time = parseInt(args[2]) * 60000;

let reason = args.slice(2).join(" ");
if (!reason) reason = "No reason provided";

if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.channel.send("I do not have sufficient permissions to mute this member. Please try again");
```

Comment: I tried that but it still did not work. I will edit the code in my original post to what I now have

Comment: I actually am not. I use Glitch and it shows errors when there aren't any unless I refresh the page. Thanks